React + RHF: Cannot update a component while rendering a different component Controller
I'm using React+shadcn+react-query. I have form with two fields.
export default function MyComponent() {
    const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({...});

    ...code

    return (
        <Form {...form}>
            <form onSubmit={...)}>
                <FieldOne />
                <FieldTwo />
                <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
            </form>
        </Form>
    );
}

Field two depends on field one - if field one changes, a http request is made inside field two that is enabled only when fieldOne has a value:
export const FieldTwo = () => {
    const form = useFormContext();
    const watchFieldOne = form.watch("fieldOne", undefined);
    const query = useGetSomethingBasedOnFieldOne(watchFieldOne);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (query.data) {
            form.setValue("fieldOne", query.data.someValue);
        }
    }, [form, query.data]);

    return (
        <FormField
           control={form.control}
           ...
        />
    );
}

The very first time the fieldOne changes, I get a console warning:
Warning: Cannot update a component (`MyComponent`) while rendering a different component (`Controller`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Controller`, follow the ...

The form works, but this warning really bothers me. I tried moving all FieldTwo logic to the parent MyComponent, and everything worked without error, but code looks worse. Is the useEffect wrong? Is there another way to update the value on the form? What can I do/try to make this code better, and get rid of the error? TYIA
